# Come si chiamano strutture come 'li li', 'se se' e strutture simili?

Tags: grammar

Come si chiamano strutture verbali come *li li* o *se se* usate come segue?

> ... quelli *li li* conosco benissimo ...
>
> ... non sapevo *se se* ne fosse andata ...

Comment: Vuoi dire "quelli lì li ..."?

Comment: Ma il primo *li* è forse un *[lì](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/li/)*?

Comment: Non c'è un nome, che io sappia. Ti confondi con una cosa del tipo “essere lì lì per andarsene”?

Answer (score 7):

Nei due esempi si trovano vicino due monosillabi di suono simile/uguale non per una ragione grammaticale o sintattica che li unisce, ma per la stessa casualità che fa stare vicine di posto in treno due persone che si somigliano. Nel primo caso "lì" è un avverbio legato a quelli (indica qualcuno lontano da chi parla) e "li" il pronome diretto legato al verbo "conoscere". Nel secondo caso, il primo "se" è una congiunzione ipotetica che dipende dal verbo "(non) sapere" mentre il secondo "se" fa parte del verbo pronominale della frase subordinata, che è "andarsene"